# Android Expand and collapse for recyclerview is not working as expected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-cardview, android-expandable-list-view

I am developing an app with expandable Recyclerview. But expansion is not working as expected. Nothing works  if I click on any item that is in collapsed state after expanding another item. I want to collapse the previously expanded item automatically if click any other item.

Please see my code for the same :

```
final boolean isExpanded = position==mExpandedPosition;
holder.expandableLayout.setVisibility(isExpanded?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
if (isExpanded) {
    previousExpandedPosition = position;

}
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:position;
        notifyItemChanged(previousExpandedPosition);
        notifyItemChanged(position);



    }
});
```

Please correct me if anything is wrong with my implementation.

Comment: this is happening due to you're just notifying the current item only so try to notify previous expanded position also.

Comment: @Bhavin updated the code. Tried that as well. But sometimes it's not working if click items randomly.

Comment: i have posted an answer try that else we'll try some different thing. and also i can't understand why you're managing previousExpandedPosition as it can create issue if not managed well. and there might be chances that selected item is currently not showing in the view so onBindViewHolder method will not called.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a "previousExpandedPosition":

```
private int mExpandedPosition = -1;
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String str = mData.get(position);
        holder.mText.setText(str);
        
        final boolean isExpanded = position == mExpandedPosition;
        holder.expandableLayout.setVisibility( isExpanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1 : position;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: No hope. Still the same behaviour

Comment: I used the same exact codes and my items expand and collapse as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As i guess you're just notifying your current item that something has but not the older one which is already expanded which is causing the problem so apply changes as following.

```
....
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int previousSelectedPosition = mExpandedPosition;
        mExpandedPosition = isExpanded ? -1:position;

        notifyItemChanged(position); // here we notified our current item   
        if (previousSelectedPosition != -1) 
           notifyItemChanged(previousSelectedPosition); // here we notified past item
    }
});
....
```

Comment: Tried this. This is working fine for the first two items and after that only collapse is happening if I click other items. That clicked item is expanding if there is no expanding row.